# constructor java/C# taking in argument the mother class

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, copy

I have a class that I have derivated to add some fields.

```
class B: A  {

private sthg ;

public B(A a, String sthg){
 //
}
}
```

I wonder what I have to do in the constructor in order to have a link between my A object passed to the contructor and my object.

Thank you.

Comment: **Why** do you want to pass in an instance of the base class? You could just add a field of type `A` and store it there.

Comment: Also: you ask about "Java/C#", but tag it only as Java, but the code is neither C# nor Java (at least not compilable in either of those). Could you fix that?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create something similar to the composite design pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), is that what you are aiming for? perhaps more details to the question would help.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? Can you provide an example with meaningful classes? It would definitely help understand what you mean by "have a link between my A object ..."

Answer (score 2):

whats' wrong with inheritance?

```
class B extends A {
    public B(...) {
        super();
        ...
    }
}
```

...well, if you *really* want to have an instance of B() such as it can handle an A() instance, you can add an A parameter to B

```
class B extends A {
    A a;
    ...
    public B(A a, ...) {
        super(); 
        this.a = a;
        ...
    }
}
```

but, in this case, I really don't see what's the need to B to extends A.

```
class B {
    A a;
    ...
    public B(A a, ...) {
        this.a = a;
        ...
    }
 }
```